# Error - fatal: '$GIT_DIR' too big when trying to deploy react app to gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I have modified my json homepage as well as added scripts "predeploy" and "deploy" the repo is opened and linked to the remote. I use npm run deploy and get this error.

[screen of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmm9N.png)

Comment: I also should mention I changed my registry to accept longFileNames

Comment: Have you added your `node_modules` to `.gitignore`?

Comment: I had to rebuild the project, this somehow fixed it. I did have the node modules in the .gitignore.